# What is the best way to configure a django project

Tags: python, django

I am about to set up a project, and am wondering what the best way to do it is.
I notice some open source files have an "apps" directory, which stores all third-party apps, etc.

I was looking at the following two projects

https://github.com/josephmisiti/NewsBlur

https://github.com/dkukral/everyblock

My project will consist of code that will run multiple different (and connected) web applications.

I also found this:

https://github.com/lincolnloop/django-startproject/tree/master/django_startproject/project_template/myproject/

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This question has been covered several times. See:

- [Django tips: laying out an application](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/sep/10/django-tips-laying-out-application/)
- [Web Application (Django) typical project folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282034/web-application-django-typical-project-folder-structure)
- [Best practice folder hierarchy of a Django Web App](http://groups.google.com/group/djangoindia/browse_thread/thread/7167def9b77f3b34)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an exact 'best way' which is suitable for every project. But there are some general rules that may help you setup your project. I won't send any link about this but there are several documents and webpages, so keep Googling. It's the best way to learn some extra tricks while digging pages for a purpose.

Also, try to understand projects that is similar to the one you want to develop. You say you've been already doing it, I think it is going to be the most helpful thing you do for your project.