# Django SyntaxError on url tag in template

Tags: python, django, url, tags, templating

I have a Django app that continues to be fussy about the `{% url ... %}` templating tag. I've fixed this before, but it now it's giving me a `SyntaxError` on loading the template.

### Working backwards

Start with the relevant template lines:

```
<a href="{% url 'project-index' %}">
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</a>
```

Function I'm trying to `reverse()` to in [`views.py`](https://gist.github.com/010edeae92ef1da1b1e8):

```
def index (request):
    return render(request, "project/index.html", { "user" : request.user })
```

Url patterns (`urls.py`):

```
urlpatterns = patterns("project.views",
    url(r'^$', "index", name="project-index"),
    url(r'^login/?$', "login", name="project-login"),
    url(r'^logout/?$', "logout", name="project-logout"),
)
```

Main app included urls (`urls.py`):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('', include('project.urls')),
)
```

Here is a [gist of the traceback](https://gist.github.com/502ff8b6ed19e415f2b8).

The traceback doesn't show the exact line number for the template error, so here's what it gives me:

```
Error during template rendering
In template /Users/josh/Dropbox/Projects/app/sc/templates/layouts/base.html, error at line 47
```

Comment: Post the actual error please. Also what django version are you using?

Comment: @Hedde 1.4.2. I added the traceback to the question, but also here's the error off the top of the page: https://gist.github.com/da71d2e1ec70e40b3eae

Comment: This seems to be some syntax problem in your views.py. You may want to look at that.

Comment: @Rohan Views.py loads fine, and the Django error page explicitly says error during template rendering.

Comment: @JoshK, I would suggest to double check, as I still suspect that this is issue in views.py. Template is trying to resolve the view function but getting some syntax error.

Comment: @Rohan I added a link to [`views.py`](https://gist.github.com/010edeae92ef1da1b1e8), you're welcome to check it out.

Comment: @Rohan I did some more digging into `views.py`. If I replace line 19 with something like `return HttpResponse("Hello, world")` it returns that fine. I don't think this is a syntax error in actual code at that point unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The "old" url tag doesn't accept quotes but this will be deprecated. Use `{% load url from future %}` in Django <1.5. Check the Forwards compatibility section in documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: I've tried it with quotes, with double quotes, without quotes. No change. I've also tried adding `{% load url from future %}` and using quotes, still no luck.

Comment: your app is called project? that's not really conform project [layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216829/django-directory-structure/11222631#11222631) but the url syntax usually is `{% url 'appname:viewname' %}`

Comment: @Hedde Working on my naming, but for kicks here's a [gist using 1.5's `load url from future` and the `app:viewname` showing the same error](https://gist.github.com/e14f8f0aa78f4098a988).