# Django project problems with admin panel

Tags: django, django-models

I'm storing all my models in one folder called models, it's working fine for me. But there is some problems with admin.py, where should I store this file? Within models folder or within app folder? When i'n trying to insert models into admin panel i got an error.

Error:

```
TypeError at /admin/

'module' object is not iterable

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:9004/admin/
Django Version:     1.4.5
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'module' object is not iterable

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in register, line 74
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.7
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/***/**/**/Testcase_Project',
'/home/***/**/**/Testcase_Project',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']

Server time:    Sat, 16 Mar 2013 11:31:39 +0200
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response

                                request.path_info)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve

                for pattern in self.url_patterns:

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in url_patterns

            patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in urlconf_module

                self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module

        __import__(name)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/***/***/***/Testcase_Project/Testcase_Project/urls.py in <module>

    admin.autodiscover()

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py in autodiscover

                import_module('%s.admin' % app)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module

        __import__(name)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/home/***/***/***/Testcase_Project/Testcase_Project/admin.py in <module>

    admin.site.register(test_cases)

    ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in register

            for model in model_or_iterable:

    ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: It's better within app folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to separate objects into modules into packages etc. You just have to remember that Django only looks for an `admin.py` and `models.py` file in a package's root by default. The solution here is to explicitly import the required files, a good place to do this in is `__init__` files which are compiled first.

so e.g. (Django 1.4 setup, more info on Django structures [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216829/django-directory-structure/11222631#11222631)):

```
/project_root
    /project
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
    /app
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
    manage.py
```

can be converted to:

```
/project_root
    /project
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
    /app
        __init__.py  # <- import statements
        /admin
            admin_foo.py
            admin_bar.py
        /models
            model_foo.py
            model_bar.py
    manage.py
```

Then in your `__init__.py` inside your app folder add:

```
from .models.model_foo import Foo
from .models.model_bar import Bar
from .admin.admin_foo import FooAdmin
from .admin.admin_bar import BarAdmin
```

And because of how installed apps defines things, you should not forget to add the app_label attribute to the model Meta class:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # fields...
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app'


class Bar(models.Model):
    # fields...
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app'
```

Comment: I did such thing but models not showing up in admin panel...

Comment: Probably because there's still some old compiled hidden `.pyc` files in your app folder, delete them and you should be fine. `find . -type f -name "*.pyc" | xargs rm;`

Comment: i got : "'module' object is not iterable" error

Comment: that sounds like a completely different issue, but you could add the stacktrace to your post to make sure

Comment: yeaaah i got it there was syntax mistake.