# What is the right location for my django translation files?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, mezzanine, django-i18n

I'm giving my first steps with python/django/mezzanine so please bear with me.

I modified a translation file and compiled it ok.

The translated file belongs to mezzanine's blog application and the only place I found out I could place it to test was at the blog app's locale folder (~/MY_VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/blog/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES).

It worked fine, but my guts tell me there has to be a way I can have this file(s) in some other location WITHIN my own mezzanine application so:

```
I can easily maintain it and
I don't have to keep my whole virtual environment in my SCM's repository.
```

Am I in the right track? If so, where should I place my new own translation files?

Thanks a lot in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever place your virtual environment into your repository. It makes no sense. You will somewhen deploy your application, and besides it is a good approach to use virtual environments on your server, you might also deploy your app on Heroku or another [PaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service), and then you will only need the app source in your repository.

Django 1.5 picks up the translation files in the following [order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/i18n/#using-translations-in-your-own-projects):

- First, it looks for a locale directory in the application directory of the view that’s being called. If it finds a translation for the selected language, the translation will be installed.
- Next, it looks for a locale directory in the project directory. If it finds a translation, the translation will be installed.
- Finally, it checks the Django-provided base translation in django/conf/locale.

So in your case I assume that the blog application is a package installed via pip (therefore it is in the site-packages folder) you can choose the second option and create a locale directory in your project directory, and put your translation in there.

Comment: JUst to make sure: Should they be at MY_PROJECT/blog/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES or at MY_PROJECT/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES??

Comment: None of the indicated paths worked for me. I even tried copying the translation files to BOTH folders. What am I missing here? naming conventions? The files are named like the originals django.po and django.mo

Comment: I tried the LOCALE_PATHS and did not wor work either. Please take a look at the [this paste](http://pastebin.com/c8pvKLXQ) that shows my directory tree and value of LOCALE_PATHS at the edn of settings.py

Comment: are you using django 1.4+? then I would first recommend that you adapt your directory structure to match the structure proposed there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216829/django-directory-structure

Comment: also make sure that LOCALE_PATHS is the absolute (= the entire) path. you only used the relative path. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths