# Django - No module name site.urls

Tags: python, django, openshift

As [this other SO post shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216829/django-directory-structure), my Django 1.4 directory structure globally looks like:

```
wsgi/
   champis/
       settings.py
       settings_deployment.py
       urls.py
   site/
       static/
           css/
               app.css
       templates/some_app/foo.html
       __init__.py
       urls.py
       views.py
       models.py
   manage.py
```

The project is `champis`, the app is `site`. My *PYTHONPATH* includes the `wsgi` folder (well from Django standards it should be named after the project i.e. `champis`, but here I'm starting from an [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) [django-example Git project](https://github.com/openshift/django-example)).

My `champis.urls`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^champis/', include('site.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My `site.urls` module then routes to specific pages, but when trying to access on local, I have the error:

```
http://127.0.0.1/champis => no module name site.urls
```

The `site` app is present in my `INSTALLED_APPS`, and my `ROOT_URLCONF` is `champis.urls`.
Do you have an idea why ? Even moving the `site` folder into the `champis` one didn't help.

Comment: Does your `site` folder contain an `__init__.py`?

Comment: Is `site` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @Alasdair, Brandon: yes and yes. I'll edit my post to mention that.

Comment: Should site.urls be a string?

Comment: what about just champis.site.urls?  It's weird because it seems perfectly fine the way it is.

Comment: What does `urls.py` in `site` contain?

Comment: Have you tried deleting any/all of your .pyc files? Everything looks ok to me.

Comment: @chawk that's exactly what I meant with my comment. I suspect the application is clashing with another 'site', calling the application directly would probably solve this

Comment: yeah I wonder if he figured it out?

Comment: @chawk: I'll try and let you know, did not think about this one. Brandon: I'll try that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this problem by:

- adding an `__init__.py` at project level
- renaming my `site` app into `web` (app name seemed to be colliding with... something that I did not find)

Here is my current directory structure now:

```
wsgi/
   champis/
       settings.py
       settings_deployment.py
       urls.py
   web/                <= changed app name
       static/
           css/
               app.css
       templates/some_app/foo.html
       __init__.py
       urls.py
       views.py
       models.py
   manage.py
   __init__.py         <= added
```