# How to set STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT so the path used is not hard coded?

Tags: django, django-settings, django-1.6, os.path

In my settings.py file both the `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` both currently point to a hard coded location. For example the `STATIC_ROOT` path is:

```
/home/ian/projectname/mysite/appname/static
```

I know this will cause problems when I deploy my project.

Looking around I can see that I need to make use of `os.path` but the countless examples have just confused me.

I have tried to view different permutations of setting this file (or getting the example value as used to set the BASE_DIR) however as the screen shot shows I am missing something because it is complaining about the **file** value.

In case of need I am using Django 1.6

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you are receiving this error as a result of appending the `__file__` in interactive shell:

```
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

The shell doesn't detect the current file path in `__file__` as it relates to your `filepath` in which you added this line. To work, for example, you will need to include this in `file.py`:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Then, run this from the command line:

```
python file.py
```

This is because `__file__` relates to whatever the `filepath` of `file.py` is.

In the case of `settings.py`, use this to get the root directory of your Django project:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

You can then use `os.path.join()` to join other relative paths, such as:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

For more information on how to lay out your Django project directory, read this: [Common structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216829/django-directory-structure/11222631#11222631)

Answer (score 3):

The usual practice (suggested in [django official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) also) is to have a `BASE_DIR` setting that gets the current working directory from the `__file__`:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Then, using `os.path.join()` other relative paths are constructed, for example:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Note that `__file__` is only available for the module, it doesn't make sense to use it on a console.

Comment: Thanks for the very prompt response, using the example of BASE_DIR, if I was able to see its value would it be "/home/ian/projectname/mysite/"? If so how do I use os.path.join to go another two folders down? i.e. /appname/static ?

Comment: @IanCarpenter well, usually static root is on the project level, not app level. If you have multiple apps with their own static files - use `staticfiles` built-in app, see more at [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).