# Django rest framwork folder structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

i found this question in stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282034/web-application-django-typical-project-folder-structure).
but I still haven't received the answer to my question, what exactly is the standard project structure in Django?

Answer (score 1):

```
my_project/
├─ my_project/
│  ├─ settings.py
│  ├─ wsgi.py
│  ├─ asgi.py
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ urls.py
├─ my_app/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ urls.py
│  ├─ models.py
│  ├─ views.py
│  ├─ admin.py/
│  ├─ apps.py
│  ├─ tests.py
```

Does that answer your question?

If not, please write down what you do not understand